# VisualSVN 32 to 64 upgrade (2.5.x -> 3.3)

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We're on VisualSVN Server 2.5.24 (runs with Subverson 1.7.x). Support is ending re VisualSVN Server 2.5. Advises upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.3 (which runs with Subversion 1.8.x).  It's available as 64 bit (and 32 bit).

Operating System is Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit)

VisualSVN Server 2.5 is 32bit, and lives at "C:\Program Files (x86)".

If upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.3 64 bit, I assume it would go to "C:\Program Files".

They've in the past recommended just running the setup to upgrade, but this time it's going to also be 32 bit to 64 bit and so different directories!

Anyone done this?

Any trouble?

Is this one of those situations where it's actually better to uninstall and then install new from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN Server will keep original installation directory on upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit.

It's not a problem to have 64-bit application installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll report back on how I get on. Aiming to try it over this weekend. I'm not too keen on leaving it in "C:\Program Files (x86)\" even if it's technically possible, as a little untidy and maybe confusing for someone else later, but I may end up with that for the short-term.

Comment: @BarryEverett that's completely not an issue and should not cause any confusion I'd say.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I should have avoided the whole upgrade question, and actually asked "How to migrate/move 64bit Visual SVN install location from C:\Program Files (x86)" to "C:\Program Files"

Answer (score 0):

### IMPORTANT:

> You **must not uninstall** VisualSVN Server when you upgrade it! Read
>   the related KB article [Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.3](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00085/) and if
>   you use Multisite Repository Replication feature (i.e. VDFS), make
>   sure to read ["Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.3 in a multisite
>   environment"](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00086/) article.

When you upgrade VisualSVN Server 1.x or 2.x to VisualSVN Server 3.x 64-bit, VisualSVN Server's MSI (Windows Installer) automatically performs all tasks necessary for the successful upgrade of the server. In other words, VisualSVN Server 32-bit gets automatically upgraded to 64-bit version. And yes, **the installation location does not change by design**. It is valid to keep 64-bit application in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Moreover, switching the installation location in the upgrade process can result into multiple issues, e.g. it may break hook scripts that have the location of svn CLI tools hardcoded to the original location of VisualSVN Server.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect it won't move the whole directory structure from program files x86 to program files.

Comment: @BarryEverett If you upgrade VisualSVN Server 2.5 to 3.3, you will get 64-bit VisualSVN Server installed on 64-bit machine. It's installation location will be kept untouched.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. which is also what I don't want.  I want x64 in just program files. And no left over files in x86 (even if visual svn did upgrade it). Never mind. Leave to me and I will see what works out.

Comment: @BarryEverett as a VisualSVN techsupport engineer I just don't understand why you are concerned about the path.

Comment: The reason is just tidiness. It's just a directory name afterall, but I like 32bit/x86 stuff in "C:\Program Files (x86)". And no 64bit/x64 stuff in a directory marked specifically as x86.   That's all.    Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I do also note you say "broken hook scripts"...,

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall 2.5 and when installing fresh 64-bit version, just make sure to choose the same path for repository root. Shouldn't be a problem.

I would, though, make a backup of all repositories before these operations - just in case, as usual.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is misleading and harmful. VisualSVN Server must **NOT** be uninstalled when doing an upgrade: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00085/

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try a few things, and maybe uninstalling will also be in the mix, along with Ivan Zhakov suggestion. We use Acronis to backup servers, so I will have something to rollback to.  I'll copy the folder etc, have a quick look through registry settings, and scan for config of paths etc in XML/INI/whatever config files for paths.    I'll get back to both of you and answer this when I've done it.   Our Repositories are on a different disk/partition already so won't be affected.

Comment: @bahrep, thank you for downvote explanation. However, I believe the anser is not misleading,because he's switching from 32 to 64 bit. Proper way would be to not have the thing installed twice, once in program files and another time in program files (x86). And it's also not in any way harmful. What you loos is the server settings (that's actually just the info about what port is used and if SSL is used, nothing more). Sources are certainly NOT lost.

Comment: @BarryEverett I guess my answer should make it a bit clearer (I've just posted it). When upgrading VisualSVN Server 2.x 32-bit to 3.x 64-bit, the installation location is kept untouched; VisualSVN Server does not get "installed twice".

Comment: Also agreed.  Leave with me.